# DialoFlow problem recognizing "plus" in International region code phone number

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have create a simple intent with some training phrases like (use .. only to no get a real number in this question :) ):

> plus397788..
>
> plus4445454..
>
> My number is +39......

For now only those three example, defining a parameter name associated to the phone number with an entity of type @sys.phone.number

Now the problem is that when the input is by Microphone we get something like:

Speaker say "plus33545" -> DialogFlow extract "class44545"..  so class and not plus

Speaker say "plus33545" -> DialogFlow extract  "glass39"....   so glass and not plus

so something that "could" song similar to class but it's not, even with different speaker.

We can filter this problem in webhook, but is there any way to automate the understanding of this phone number (this is a standard international phone number in my opinion)?

Comment: Observed same behaviour with the dialogflow for the phonenumber scenarios.
Suppose user says :'My number is +1234', it will consider it as 'My number is plus 1 2 3 4' if there is pauses in user's statements. The one way is used to consider you have static country code and add the country code with the phone number.

Comment: See my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442282/dialoflow-problem-recognizing-plus-in-international-region-code-phone-number